# CQL_FILTER on multilayer request where only one layer needs filtered

Tags: geoserver, cql-filter

I have an image mosaic timeseries layer called agdd as well as a shapefile layer called cb_2014_us_state_500k that displays us state boundaries.

I can stack both layers with the following query:

```
http://server/geoserver/gdd/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=gdd:agdd,gdd:cb_2014_us_state_500k&time=2016-01-10&styles=&bbox=-125.020833333333,24.0625,-66.479166666662,49.937500000002&width=1400&height=700&srs=EPSG:4269&format=application/openlayers
```

The result looks like so:
[image]

I can use CQL_FITLER=NAME='Texas' to only show the Texas border in the cb_2014_us_state_500k layer:

```
http://server/geoserver/gdd/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=gdd:cb_2014_us_state_500k&CQL_FILTER=NAME=%27Texas%27&styles=&bbox=-179.148909,-14.548699,179.77847,71.365162&width=768&height=330&srs=EPSG:4269&format=application/openlayers
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

Now I'm trying to both the combine layers AND filter the states layer to Texas all in one request. I tried to use a semicolon in the CQL_FILTER to specify that there are two layers, but it doesn't parse:

```
http://server/geoserver/gdd/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=gdd:agdd,gdd:cb_2014_us_state_500k&CQL_FILTER=;NAME='Texas'&time=2016-01-10&styles=&bbox=-125.020833333333,24.0625,-66.479166666662,49.937500000002&width=1400&height=700&srs=EPSG:4269&format=application/openlayers
```

Any ideas how to write this request?

Here is the error I get when using an empty filter for one of the layers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://geoserver-dev.usanpn.org:80/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
      Could not parse CQL filter list.
Encountered &quot;&lt;EOF&gt;&quot; at line 1, column 12.
Was expecting one of:
    &quot;not&quot; ...
    &quot;id&quot; ...
    &quot;in&quot; ...
    &lt;IDENTIFIER&gt; ...
    &lt;DATE_TIME&gt; ...
    &quot;(&quot; ...
    &quot;[&quot; ...
    &lt;DATE&gt; ...
    &quot;-&quot; ...
    &lt;INTEGER_LITERAL&gt; ...
    &lt;FLOATING_LITERAL&gt; ...
    &lt;STRING_LITERAL&gt; ...
    &quot;true&quot; ...
    &quot;false&quot; ...
    &quot;point&quot; ...
    &quot;linestring&quot; ...
    &quot;polygon&quot; ...
    &quot;multipoint&quot; ...
    &quot;multilinestring&quot; ...
    &quot;multipolygon&quot; ...
    &quot;geometrycollection&quot; ...
    &quot;envelope&quot; ...
    &quot;include&quot; ...
    &quot;exclude&quot; ...
     Parsing : NAME=&apos;Ohio&apos;;.
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Comment: According to http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html using semicolon should do it. Perhaps an empty filter has not been tested. Could you make a copy of the cb_2014_us_state_500k layer with another name and make a new trial with a filter like NAME='Texas';NAME='Ohio' ?

Comment: Your test worked with specifying the boarders layer twice and filtering on two different states (there was no error). I'm appending to the question the error I get back when using an empty filter on one of the layers.

Comment: I can get it to work using this, but it's pretty hacky: &CQL_FILTER=true=true;NAME='Texas'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass an *empty* filter into CQL but you can say you want *all* the features from that layer by using the special `INCLUDE` filter. So your query should be something like:

```
CQL_FILTER=INCLUDE;NAME='Texas'
```

You can find a full reference the the ECQL filter language that GeoServer uses [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html#filter-ecql-reference).